# Web Audio API - Pitch detection loses pitch on long notes

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, audiocontext

bsd

Hello, I am trying to achieve vocal pitch detection, I have tried several libs & approaches and eventually found this pitch detection code here :

https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/

The problem is, when singing / humming the same note to the pitch detector, it finds the right note, but after a couple of seconds or so, the pitch gets lost, at first it jumps a couple of octaves higher, and then it gets completely lost.

Why is that happening? why when singing long notes the pitch gets lost?

Comment: There is a pull request on that repository with an algorithm that has given me far better results: https://github.com/cwilso/PitchDetect/pull/23
I suggest giving that one a go, it seems to work a lot better

Comment: Here's a direct download for the repository if you'd like to give it a go: https://github.com/dalatant/PitchDetect/archive/master.zip